# Add a RealityKit's "rcproject" to ARKit's SCNScene

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, realitykit

I am trying to add a `.rcproject` to my SCNView. I am working with SwitftUI an totally lost. I have no idea how to add it.

Currently I am able to detect my objects in the room with ARKit. But I also want to add my Scene from RealityKit at this anchor point.

Is there a way to do so?

```swift
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
             didAdd node: SCNNode, 
              for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        
    if let objectAnchor = anchor as? ARObjectAnchor {
        let name = objectAnchor.referenceObject.name!
        print("You found a \(name) object")
        let titleNode = createTitleNode(name)
        node.addChildNode(titleNode)
            
        let example_scene = try! RealityExample.loadScene()
        arView.scene.anchors.append(example_scene) 
        // not possible, because this is not a SCNScene   
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can't read in](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource) Reality Composer project (`.rcproject`) into ARSCNView's scene (`.scn`). That's because SceneKit isn't able to handle RealityKit's objects and hierarchy. In SceneKit there are [nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/gaming/scenekit) (`SCNNode` class) connected to scene's root node (however, if you're using SceneKit with ARKit, nodes must be also tethered with ARAnchors), but in RealityKit there are [entities](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene) (`ModelEntity` class) connected to scene through `AnchorEntities`. These two frameworks are totally different.

The only file format RealityKit and SceneKit can share is Pixar's **`.usdz`**.

Comment: thanks for the information, but how then i am able to use an real world scanned anchor for the scene?

Comment: because i try to track an anchor from arkit to set the scene from realitykit on top.

Comment: thanks for your support, here is the new question :-D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304656/using-arkit-anchor-to-place-realitykit-scene