# How to keep a plane in place as the phone moves?

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am creating a Plane with a VideoMaterial and placing it over a recognized image.  The anchor for the plane is created like this:

```
let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: imageAnchor.transform)
```

And that works fine for the initial location.  But I want it to stay in place as I move the phone around, and it doesn't.  It doesn't quite follow the phone, either, but it moves in the same general direction.

I think the fix for this is to keep updating the anchor's transform in didUpdate, but to what?  I only have the current transform of the imageAnchor and no way to convert it to world coordinates.  I tried using it unconverted and the plane ended in an entirely wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tracking native and ARKit anchors in RealityKit

---

Native RealityKit's [case image(group: String, name: String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52893075/what-is-aranchor-exactly/52899502#52899502) automatically tracks its target (image).

```
AnchorEntity(.image(group: "ARGroup", name: "myImage"))
```

If you prefer to track ARKit's `ARImageAnchor`, then use [session(_:didUpdate:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304656/using-arkit-anchor-to-place-realitykit-scene/65309335#65309335) delegate method.

```
AnchorEntity(anchor: arImageAnchor)
```

Comment: Andy, thank you for your help!  Your posts have been super helpful to me as I've been learning ARKit.  Way better than Apple's documentation.  I didn't do exactly what you suggested here, but it led me to a partial solution.

This question was actually a simplified version of what I'm doing.  I've posted a new question with more info at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75943774/keeping-entity-anchored-in-place-as-phone-moves

Thank you in advance if you are able to take a look at it!