# Keeping model anchored in place when a tracking image is hidden

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am doing the following:

- detect an image with an ARWorldTrackingConfiguration with maximumNumberOfTrackedImages set to 1
- when the image disappears and didUpdate is called, create a plane with a VideoMaterial and add it to an anchor created with `AnchorEntity(.world(transform: imageAnchor.transform))`

As the video plays, the plane is more or less anchored at the spot where the image was, but not perfectly. It still moves around a bit as the phone moves.

Is there anything I can do to make it stay perfectly still?  didUpdate is never called again after the tracked image disappears, so the usual technique of updating the transform there is not available to me.

Answer (score 1):

#### Re-anchoring technique

You can place your model in the scene using image tracking and then reanchor it preserving model's current world space position. For that, implement [reanchor(_:preservingWorldTransform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/anchorentity/reanchor(_:preservingworldtransform:)) instance method inside `session(_:didUpdate:)` delegate's method.

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

extension ViewController : ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {

        if anchor.isActive {
            anchor.reanchor(.world(transform: sphere.transform.matrix), 
                    preservingWorldTransform: true)
        }
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    var anchor = AnchorEntity(.image(group: "AR", name: "image"))
    let sphere = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.05))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.session.delegate = self
        anchor.addChild(sphere)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy, thanks for your help!  I have been playing around with this some more and realized that in your sample the sphere doesn't quite hold still... it appears to roll around a bit.  When I substitute a plane for the sphere, the movement is a lot more noticeable.  Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Hi janineanne, reanchoring from local space to global space always requires a small amount of time during which the model becomes unstable.